# Homework: Help transalate pseudo code into C code

Tags: c

We are going over a sample test paper for a course and would like assistance from a C programmer translating pseudo code into C code.

We are having a disagreement becasue two of the possible options look correct. (I am NOT a programmer and nor are my colleagues)

The pseudo code is:

"If we have written 200 characters to the buffer variable, the stack should stop because it cannot hold any more data."

The possible answers are:

1. If (i >= 200) then exit
2. If (i > 200) then exit
3. If (i < 200) then exit
4. If (i <= 200) then exit

We know the answer is NOT 3 and 4.

I beleive that the answer is "2" (if 200 characters have been written; end the program), but my colleagues believe that the correct answer is "1" (if 200 or more characters have been written; end the program).

Please advise as to what the correct answer is.

Comment: C doesn't have a `then` at all. They're *all* incorrect.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be (1), but I would rather say not enough information has been given.

Comment: None of the possible answers are correct, simply because neither is C. There is no "then" keyword, no "exit" keyword. It is still a pseudo code.

Comment: I think he needs the C code for the correct answer, which can only be determined if we know how `i` is indexed (from zero or one or something else).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any "200 or more" or "more than 200" in the pseudo code. Maybe the right answer is `if (i == 200) then exit`.

Answer (score 2):

Pretend you're the computer. Every time you write a character to the buffer, you increment `i`.

Assuming you start at 0, which is normal in C, after you've written a single character, `i` would be 1. After the second character, `i` is 2. Extrapolate.

Comment: I guess he/she will have to pretend to be a central processor unit rather than a program :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "If (i >= 200) then exit" to me.

Answer (score 1):

In C code, the angle bracket means exactly the same as in mathematics:
`<` = *smaller than*
`>` = *greater than*

And if you add an `=`sign, you get *smaller/greater **or equal***.

If `i` is the number of characters written to the stack, then i >= 200 (*i is greater or equal to 200*) is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well none of the answers is actually C. You are translating a statement into psudo code (sorry I know its symantics but there is still a distinction). In any case since it doesn't state more than 200 I would vote for 1. If (i >= 200) then exit myself as it states when you hit 200 so its inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

"If we have written 200 characters to the buffer variable, the stack should stop because it cannot hold any more data."

The correct answer is 1: If (i >= 200) then exit.

Here's why.

Your pseudo code specifically says, if 200 characters are written, exit.

If the answer was 2: It would only exit after 201 characters were written (since 201 > 200).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how `i` is indexed and how your loop is setup. If it is indexed by 0 (likely) and you had a buffer (`buf`) you would do something like this.

```
data_type buf[200];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  // write data to buffer
  buf[i] = data;
}
```

Therefore, when i becomes 200, the loop exits (and the condition is `i < 200`). `data_type` is what ever data you are using in the buffer. If `i` was indexed starting at one then your loop condition would be `i <= 200`.

Answer (score 0):

i vote for 1.if(i>=200) since that is what your spec says. C doesnt have 'then' keyword, and it should have been 'exit(0);' instead of just 'exit'.

```
if(i >= 200){
    exit(0);
}
```